# Views custom field select list like views custom field

Tags: views, 7, hooks

I'm looking for a module which can allow to add a select list like views customfield provides a text field.
The select list are on the based of above fields.
Example :
I have Edit and delete operations in each views row corresponding to the result.I need these operations in select list.
Any module suggestions ?

P.S. : Please don't suggest about views_php.I can write custom handlers instead of this module.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to achieve but does not do much on it's own :

- Create a new field for something like Content:NID
- Go to Theme Information in the view settings
- Find the template fie name suggested for your field
- Create that file in your theme folder eg `views-view-field--my-view--page--title.tpl.php`
- Press rescan templates in theme information (file name will go bold)
- Add the following to the file

```
<select name="ops_<?php print $row->nid; ?>">
  <option value="edit">edit</option>
  <option value="delete">delete</option>
</select>
```

It doesn't do anything on it's own, you could wrap it in a `<form>` and specify a path as your method to process it, or use jQuery to do something.

But ... There is also an excellent module called [View Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) which will probably give you all the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Rewrite the field output will not allow adding html.It will simply print the result.

Comment: You're right, I forgot that, I have changed my input formats, I've updated it to use templates.

Comment: Yeah templates is the way to do so.Also writing the custom handler is awesome.I have achieved it by writing the custom handler. But I'm looking for some contrib module stuff.